# How do I left-align the title, date and author in LaTeX?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I would like to align the title, author and date to the left of my LaTeX document. I do not have a separate title page. I have tried doing `\author{\begin{flushleft}My name\end{flushleft}}` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Which class are you using?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @BlackBird I'm using \documentclass{article}, sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: The easy solution is to NOT use \maketitle.  It is there as a convenience, not a requirement.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, you're right. If it's a one-time thing, it's better not to use it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with the `titling` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-8ex}
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\Large\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\Large}
\postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
\predate{\begin{flushleft}}
\postdate{\end{flushleft}}
\title{What the Tortoise Said to Achilles}
\author{Charles Lutwige Dodgson}
\date{1895}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Achilles had overtaken the Tortoise, and had seated himself comfortably on its back.

"So you've got to the end of our race-course?" said the Tortoise. "Even though it does consist of an infinite series of distances? I thought some wiseacre or other had proved that the thing couldn't be done?"

"It can be done," said Achilles. "It has been done! Solvitur ambulando. You see the distances were constantly diminishing; and so — "

"But if they had been constantly increasing?" the Tortoise interrupted. "How then?"

"Then I shouldn't be here," Achilles modestly replied; "and you would have got several times round the world, by this time!"

"You flatter me — flatten, I mean," said the Tortoise; "for you are a heavy weight, and no mistake! Well now, would you like to hear of a race-course, that most people fancy they can get to the end of in two or three steps, while it really consists of an infinite number of distances, each one longer than the previous one?"

"Very much indeed!" said the Grecian warrior, as he drew from his helmet (few Grecian warriors possessed pockets in those days) an enormous note-book and a pencil. "Proceed! And speak slowly, please! Short-hand isn't invented yet!"

"That beautiful First Proposition of Euclid!" the Tortoise murmured dreamily. "You admire Euclid?"

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can patch `\@maketitle` to use `flushleft` instead of `center` and `@{}l@{}` instead of `c` in the `tabular` that's used for the author's data; also `\and` needs to be patched, if there are more than one author.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% title is flush left instead of centered
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {center}
  {flushleft}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {center}
  {flushleft}
  {}{}
% author is flush left
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {{c}}
  {{@{}l@{}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\and}
  {{c}}
  {{@{}l@{}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\title{Title of the paper}
\author{Jenni \\ Some University \\ Somewhere}
\date{38 July, 2057}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Flush left title}

The title is flush left, isn't it?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the output when `\author` has more than one part.

```
\author{Jenni \\ Some University \\ Somewhere \and Jinny \\ Other University \\ Otherplace}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{align title article}
\author{john doe}
\date{November 2020}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
\begingroup
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
 % \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c}%
    \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  %\end{center}%
  \par
  \endgroup
  \vskip 1.5em}
  
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did work, but I get an error message which says "Option clash for package inputenc". Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @Jenni, remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. You must be using it with other options.

Comment: Anyway, if your latex version is recent, you don't have to load `inputenc`:  `uf8` has been the default for  two years.

Comment: @Bernard thank you both